# Convergence or divergence of $\int_2^\infty \frac{1-\cos(4-x^2)}{x-2} \, \mathrm{d}x$

Tags: calculus, integration, improper-integrals

Is the integral

$$ \int_2^\infty \frac{1-\cos(4-x^2)}{x-2} \, \mathrm{d}x $$

convergent or divergent? As the numerator goes to $0$ infinite times I can't apply the comparison test, and I can't seem to find any function to compare the limit. I thought of integrating by parts but I do not know how to prove the integral is divergent. Any hints?

Comment: Maybe you could try change of variable $u=4-x^2$ first and then see what happens.

Comment: Which one is the lower limit? I se that it was modified from $0$ to $2$.

Comment: Continuing from the comment above, note that the integrand of the resulting integral has the asymptotic expansion $$\frac{1-\cos u}{2\sqrt{u+4}(\sqrt{u+4}-2)}=\frac{1-\cos u}{2u} + \mathcal{O}\left(\frac{1}{u^2}\right).$$

Comment: While I appreciate your comment, I would prefer not to use asymptotic expansion.

Comment: I can not remember that the following holds or not: we can sequeze the function that you wrote in integral. i.e that function bigger than $0$ and less than or equal to $2/x$ as long as I didnt make a mistake

Comment: $2/x$ diverges, so if our function is smaller that doesn't tell us anything.

Comment: Then you may use integration by parts to write $$\int\frac{1-\cos(x^2-4)}{x-2}\,\mathrm{d}x=\log(x-2)-\frac{\sin(x^2-4)}{2x(x-2)}-\int\frac{(x-1)}{x^2(x-2)^2}\sin(x^2-4)\,\mathrm{d}x.$$ When using this, it is also helpful to know that $x=2$ is a removable singularity of $\frac{1-\cos(x^2-4)}{x-2}$, posing no harm to the convergence/divergence of your integral. So, you may only consider $\int_{a}^{\infty}\frac{1-\cos(x^2-4)}{x-2}\,\mathrm{d}x$ for $a>2$.

Comment: How did you get that expression?

Answer (score 2):

Define \begin{align*}f:\quad \left] 2,+\infty\right[&\longrightarrow \mathbb{R},\\ x&\longmapsto \frac{1-\cos(4-x^{2})}{x-2}=\frac{2\sin^{2}\left(2-\frac{x^{2}}{2}\right)}{x-2} \end{align*}

Now, the integral of $f$ over the open interval $]2,+\infty[$ converges *if*
$$\underbrace{\int_{2}^{\varepsilon>2}f(x)\, {\rm d}x}_{I_{1}; \text{near }2^{+}}+\underbrace{\int_{\varepsilon >2}^{+\infty}f(x)\, {\rm d}x}_{I_{2};\text{near}+\infty}$$ *both integrals $I_{1}$ and $I_{2}$ converges*.

- $\displaystyle \int_{2}^{\varepsilon >2}f(x)\, {\rm d}x$ *converges* because $\displaystyle f(x)=\frac{2\sin^{2}\left(2-\frac{x^{2}}{2}\right)}{x-2}\underset{2^{+}}{\sim}8(x-2)=g(x)$ and $\displaystyle \int_{2}^{\varepsilon>2}g(x)\, {\rm d}x$ converges.
- $\displaystyle \int_{\varepsilon >2}^{+\infty}f(x)\, {\rm d}x$ *diverges* because $f(x)=\frac{2\sin^{2}\left(2-\frac{x^{2}}{2}\right)}{x-2}\underset{+\infty}{\sim}\frac{2}{x}\sin^{2}\left(2-\frac{x^{2}}{2}\right)=h(x)$ and $\displaystyle \int_{\varepsilon >2}^{+\infty}h(x)\, {\rm d}x$ diverges.

For see that just split the integral over intervals $[k\pi,(k+1)\pi]$ with $k\in \mathbb{N}$ and then comparison with the harmonic series.

Alternatively, notice that
$$\frac{2}{x}\sin^{2}\left(2-\frac{x^{2}}{2}\right)=\frac{2}{2x}-\frac{2\cos2\left(2-\frac{x^{2}}{2}\right)}{2x}$$

But $\displaystyle \int_{\varepsilon >2}^{+\infty}\frac{2}{2x}\, {\rm d}x$ diverges and by Dirichlet's test $\displaystyle \int_{\varepsilon >2}^{+\infty}\frac{2\cos 2\left(2-\frac{x^{2}}{2}\right)}{2x}\, {\rm d}x$ converges. Hence $\displaystyle \int_{\varepsilon >2}^{+\infty}h(x)\, {\rm d}x$ diverges.

Therefore $$ \int_{2}^{+\infty}\frac{1-\cos(4-x^{2})}{x-2}\, {\rm d}x$$ *diverges*.

Comment: @hamam_Abdallah fixed, thank you

Comment: Please, could you explain why Dirichlet's test works.

Comment: @hamam_Abdallah Well, $x\mapsto  \frac{1}{x}$ is positive, monotone decreasing and bounded over $[\varepsilon >2,+\infty[$ and has limit $0$ as $x\to +\infty$ and $\lim_{N\to +\infty}\int_{\varepsilon>2}^{N}\cos(x^{2}-2^{2})\, {\rm d}x$ can be calculated as Fresnel integrals and then converges. Is it not implies that primitive of  $x\mapsto \cos(x^{2}-2^{2})$ is uniformly bounded? If no, so just apply Abel's test for improper integrals. Of course, if I am wrong, I will be aware of your observations to try to correct my argument if that is the case.

Comment: Ok but you didn't apply Dirichlet's test to the original function with $ x-2$ as denominator.

Comment: We have $ f\underset{+\infty}{\sim}g$ so we focus in the integrability of $g$ which doesn't have the term $(x-2)$ in the denominator. I don't understand your comment. First split the integrals over $]2,+\varepsilon]$ and $[\varepsilon, +\infty[$ then study the integrals by separates.

Comment: Ok thanx a lot for taking of your precious time.

Comment: You're welcome and I hope it's clear now.Of course if my solution has a bad argument or doesn't work I'll be on the lookout to try to correct it if possible.

Answer (score 1):

*Alternative solution*:

Let
$$I_n := \int_3^{\sqrt{2n\pi + 4}} \frac{1 - \cos(4 - x^2)}{x - 2}\mathrm{d} x
\overset{x = \sqrt{y + 4}} = \int_5^{2n\pi} \frac{1 - \cos y}{\sqrt{y + 4} - 2}\, \frac{1}{2\sqrt{y + 4}}\mathrm{d} y.$$

We have
\begin{align*}
 I_n &= \int_5^{2n\pi} \frac{1 - \cos y}{y}\, \frac{\sqrt{y + 4} + 2}{2\sqrt{y + 4}}\mathrm{d} y\\[6pt]
 &\ge \int_5^{2n\pi} \frac{1 - \cos y}{y}\, \frac{\sqrt{y + 4}}{2\sqrt{y + 4}}\mathrm{d} y\\[6pt]
 &= \int_5^{2n\pi} \frac{1 - \cos y}{2y}\mathrm{d} y\\[6pt]
 &\ge \sum_{k=2}^n \int_{(2k-1)\pi - \pi/2}^{(2k-1)\pi + \pi/2} \frac{1 - \cos y}{2y}\mathrm{d} y\\[6pt]
 &\ge \sum_{k=2}^n \int_{(2k-1)\pi - \pi/2}^{(2k-1)\pi + \pi/2} \frac{1}{2y}\mathrm{d} y\\[6pt]
 &= \sum_{k=2}^n \frac12\ln\frac{(2k - 1)\pi + \pi/2}{(2k - 1)\pi - \pi/2}\\
 &\ge \sum_{k=2}^n \frac12 
 \left(1 - \frac{(2k - 1)\pi - \pi/2}{(2k - 1)\pi + \pi/2}\right)\\
 &= \sum_{k=2}^n \frac{1}{4k - 1}\\
    &\ge \sum_{k=2}^n \frac{1}{4k}
\end{align*}
where we have used
$\ln u \ge 1 - u^{-1}$ for all $u\ge 1$ (easy to prove).

Thus, $\int_2^\infty \frac{1-\cos(4-x^2)}{x-2} \, \mathrm{d}x$ is divergent.

Answer (score 0):

**hint**

Let $$f(x)=\frac{1-\cos(x^2-4)}{x-2}$$

$ f$ is continuous at $ (2,\infty) $ and is then locally integrable and positive at $(2,+\infty)$.

near $ 2^+ $ , we have

$$\lim_{x\to2^+}f(x)=\lim_{x\to 2^+}\frac{(x^2-4)^2}{2(x-2)}=0$$

thus
$$\int_2^3f(x)dx\text{  is convergent}$$

Comment: The lower bound for the sine function is not true for all $Y\geq 0$, only for $0\leq Y \leq \frac{\pi}{2}$. Just think about it, it would mean that $\sin$ takes arbitrary large values on the real line.

Comment: @Gary Yes , you are right, i deleted it. Thank you very much.